# url file path direct to root

Tags: url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I want the homepage of my domain to point to my correct site page without all the filepath showing.

**currently my structure is set up as:**

root/working_name/site_pages/homepage.php

root/working_name/site_pages/sitepage2.php

root/working_name/site_pages/sitepage3.php

**i want the web url to simply say**

root/homepage.php

root/sitepage2.php

root/sitepage3.php

i want to avoid changing any of my actual folder and file locations because this will mean that i have to change all of the references and it could get quite complicated. so is their anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to .htaccess (in root folder); you can do this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ working_name/site_pages/$1    [QSA,L]    
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: i am doing some research to find out about mod_rewrite. but all the references to it, say that it is an 'apache based rewrite engine'. so does this mean that it only works on my localhost, or can i also use it on my godaddy webserver.

Comment: yes mod_rewrite is an apache module; and almost all web hosting companies support it. check with godaddy or just create a php file with only this <?php phpinfo(); ?> and access through a web browser to see all php/apache modules

Comment: ok. but what value is supposed to be in {REQUEST_FILENAME} do i enter the file name/address in the root that i want the user to see? so for example, i would write testingthis.php inside request_filename if i wanted the user to see  sitename.com/testingthis.php and how do i say which page this needs to redirect to?

Comment: You don't need to touch that just add it to your .htacess as is. This allow your visitors to visit /root/working_name/site_pages/(whatever.php) by entering /root/(whatever.php)

Comment: ok. i see what you mean. that worked. thanks! the only problem is now my relative filepaths are not working properly. is their a workaround for this? without having to change the document relative filepaths?

Comment: Nothing can be done in .htaccess to fix relative urls but you can add this to your html: <base href="[http://host/root/working_name/](http://host/root/working_name/)" /> (that must go between <head></head>)